# How to train a model to predict the number of people at a certain bus stop before they cumulate in large numbers?

Tags: machine-learning, ai-design, prediction, ai-development

Each person probably uses an app that tracks his/her position periodically and sends it to our servers. What I want is to use these data to train a model to predict the rush hours of each bus-stop on the map, so we can send extra buses to handle the predicted cumulation before it happens.

I have no experience in AI nor machine learning. So, which model should I use to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a recurrent neural network on saved data to train a predictive model based on past data.

Comment: Maybe you should provide more details about your suggestions. For example, why would an RNN be suited for this task?

Answer (score 0):

[H2O's AutoML is the thing that you are looking for](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/automl.html) believe me it will make your life super easy.

So how it generally works is:

- You have data and want to make sense out of it by making a prediction/classification and whole other array of things, in your case prediction.
- Suppose there are 50 prediction algorithms out there, it's highly unlikely that an individual knows all of them. That's where AutoML comes into the picture.
- You give AutoML some part of your processed data and tell it to find a perfect algorithm that he thinks you should use on this data for this type of prediction. See the usage of the AutoML's API in the doc and videos on youtube.
- It then gives you a list of best algorithms that AutoML thinks is best based on the loss function that you specify. There are many other parameters that you can specify in the AutoML's API.
- Pick top 1-2 and tune the hyperparameters of the algorithm.
- That's it.

Even then if you are not happy with the performance of your system try out [ensemble learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning) before you jump for the power of neural nets which comes with lots of complexities and performance issues.